# Find values from list of map using streams

Tags: java, dictionary, arraylist, java-8, java-stream

```
List<Map<String, Object>> sqlResult = new ArrayList<>();
```

The list of map above contains following records:

```
1. facilityId="1", shipmentMethod="NEXT_DAY"

2. facilityId="2", shipmentMethod="STANDARD"
```

I want to find `shipmentMethod` where `facilityId` is `"1"` using java streams.

Also, I want to fetch only one record.

Comment: Please add your current solution/attempt

Comment: What have you tried before? Why didn't that solve your problem? Why couldn't these attempts be salvaged? Where did you look for answerd? Why do you need streams?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `filter`:

```
Object shipmentMethods = sqlResult.stream() // stream maps
    .filter(m -> m.get("facilityId").equals("1")) // filter only those, that have facilityId = "1"
    .map(m -> m.get("shipmentMethod")) // get only shipmentMethod
    .findAny().orElse(/* default value */); // get only one value
```

Comment: *lost* it on last line [: -|